# Can we use open shift for react native app?

Tags: react-native, docker, kubernetes, devops, openshift

Is it possible to use open shift in React Native app?

Basically I want to know for what openshift is used?

I am building a React Native application for a graduation projects and supervisor asked me that openshift is necessary and without it project will not be accepted.

So i need help in setting up openshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift is a Platform as a Service (PaaS) product from Red Hat that allows you to develop, host, and scale server-side applications in a cloud environment. React Native, on the other hand, is a framework for building mobile applications which run on Android, iOS and/or Windows mobile devices.

While you don't run a React Native application on OpenShift directly, OpenShift can be used to host the server-side part of your application. For example, if your React Native app needs a backend to handle tasks like user authentication, data storage, or business logic, you could build this backend service using a suitable language (like Node.js or Python) and then host this service on OpenShift.

Your React Native app would then communicate with this backend service over the network, sending requests and receiving responses. So, in this way, OpenShift can play a crucial role in the infrastructure for your React Native application, even though the React Native app itself is distributed through app stores (i.e. Google Play Store, Apple App Store) and runs on users' devices.

Comment: Thank for such detailed explanation. I was implementing local sqlite db for react native app as it is a graduation and training project. But now I think I have to build backend APIs and deploy these using openshift. As openshift is a requirement for the project. Openshift, is it free? And can I use it on Windows?

Comment: Can you suggest some resources for leaning openshift for windows. I have no idea about openshift. I just want to learn for graduation and company training project.

Comment: @MOHDSAQUIB Since you are developing the app using React Native, I suppose you are familiar with JS/TS. So, it would be much easier for you to develop the backend using Node JS. Once the backend is created, you can use OpenShift to deploy the backend with ease using OpenShift. You can use YouTube to learn about all of these for free.

Comment: I haven't used Nodejs but have some experience with django. But i think will go with nodejs for learning purpose. I think there are not much properly organised tutorial on youtube, i wasn't able to find one. So if have any kind of resources it will be helpful

Comment: Which AI did you use to generate this text?